# Filtro em Json no AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic, filtro

Gostaria como consigo filtrar esse JSON pelo COD e trazer somente o escolhido.
Estou trazendo o valor do código pela url e gostaria de filtrar apenas para apresentar o nome da opção escolhida.
OBS: O usuário não irá digitar o valor pois estava em uma lista na tela anterior em que ele escolheu.
Estou utilizando AngularJS
Exemplo:

```
{"COD":"15","NOME":"14.01 Histórico Escolar."},
{"COD":"16","NOME":"14.02 Histórico Escolar - Regime de Urgência"}
```

Então, gostaria de filtrar apenas pela coluna COD e trazer e apresentar na tela o NOME.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ANGULAR FILTER**

Para solucionar o teu problema basta usar os [FIltros](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) do Angular, segue exemplo:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.valores =  [
      {
        "COD":"15",
        "NOME":"14.01 Histórico Escolar."
      },
      {
        "COD":"16",
        "NOME":"14.02 Histórico Escolar - Regime de Urgência"
      }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Buscar por ID" ng-model="filtro.COD">
  <div ng-repeat="x in valores | filter: filtro">{{x.NOME}}</div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Sim, mas eu recebo o COD pela url, ou seja, o usuario ja escolheu o item na lista so gostaria de filtra-lo para aparecer na nova pagina o item selecionado.

Comment: Você trata essa URL como? PHP?

Comment: Não, estou utilizando ionic e angular, no caso seria o seguinde processo: O usuario tem uma lista de opcoes, ele escolhe uma, e vai para outra view, e nesta outra view queria apenas mostrar o nome da opcao escolhida. Mas baseado na sua resposta eu consegui resolver o problema aqui. Muito Obrigado! :)

Answer (score 0):

Para você realizar o filtro da forma que apontou pode usar o javascript puro mesmo

```
$scope.valores =  [
  {
    "COD":"15",
    "NOME":"14.01 Histórico Escolar."
  },
  {
    "COD":"16",
    "NOME":"14.02 Histórico Escolar - Regime de Urgência"
  }]

$scope.filtrarCodigo(codigo){
   return $scope.valores.filter(function(item){ 
                                    return (item.COD == codigo)
                                });
}
```